# iOS Regular expression: Targeting currency names

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex

Simple regular expression question. Your answer will help me wrap my head around future expressions...

Say I have this string "Send today @ 1 USD to 13.6512 MXN" and I want to target USD and MXN. Is there one regular expression that will return both values?

Comment: you just want the currency names, not the values, correct?

Comment: Just the currency indicator (e.g. USD) and yes, separate matches so "USD" and "MXN".

Comment: OK cool. thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: do you want a particular programming language usage (php, javascript, etc) or just the expression to match only?

Comment: I'm trying to use this in Objective-C (iOS). Using /[A-Z]{3}/ crashes the app. What are the beginning and trailing / for?

Comment: The slashes are for a different language. You can get rid of them.

Comment: [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"[A-Z]{3}" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch error:nil] this matched "USD" but not "MXN". Not sure that's the expressions fault though, may be something else.

Comment: Nevermind, [A-Z]{3} will work, I see "rangeOfFirstMatchInString" later in the code, so I'll just have to do some refactoring to get both matches working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a way to check it myself right now, but something like /[A-Z]{3}/ should work as both are 3 characters long.

Edit: Removed ^ and $ like mason81 said.

Comment: That's pretty close, but since you're matching something inside the string (not at the start or the end) you need to leave off the ^ and the $ like this: /[A-Z]{3}/

Comment: Ahh, yeah. So used to doing regular expressions on a single input, non-string, not a full string. Sorry about that.